# Sending email using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I want to send a reply email. I found this example in microsoft examples on using EWS. The problem is I get this error when running this piece of code.

```cs
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        EmailMessage mes = new EmailMessage(service);
        string replyto = mes.Sender.Address;
        Console.WriteLine(replyto);
        mes.Subject = "Notification Received";
        mes.Body = "Your notification has successfully been added to the site";
        mes.ToRecipients.Add(replyto);
        mes.Send();
```

**Error:** *Error: You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mes.Sender.Address` has not been assigned - you cannot read a property until you assign it a value. See [`EmailMessage.Sender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage.sender%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) on MSDN for reference.

Comment: @rdk1992 - Glad to help out! Please mark this answer as correct so that it may help others with a similar issue.